# Print with no new line python

Tags: python, python-2.7

I have checked out the possible duplicates nonetheless they are not working out for me.

What I am trying to do is rotate a numpy array and I want to see this as an animation in the terminal:

```py
if __name__ ==  "__main__":
o = np.ones((10,10))
while True:
    for i in xrange(361):
        sys.stdout.write(repr(rot_position(o, i)))
```

Tried print followed by a comma and it does not work either. How can I make it always print on the same line (that works on python 2.7x)?

Comment: What _exactly_ do you mean by "print on the same spot"?  Perhaps you could post the output you're getting now vs the output you'd like to get. Do you want to overwrite each column on the console with the same `o[i]` value for each iteration of the while loop? At present, are you just getting an ever increasing line width?

Comment: You need to modify your question so that the code is an MCEV (http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: it is too much code to put in one page like rot position just alters the array in some visible way I think thats quite obvious. I got a complete and working answer thanks for the feedback though :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The python 2.x "print with no newline" is: `print("sometext"),`

But, if you're trying to do what I think you're trying to do, between your `while` and `for`, add `print("\r"),`

Here's an example of a "ticker" program that illustrates what I'm talking about.  Different, but I think it's applicable:

```
#!/usr/bin/python

import time
import sys

i = 0
hello = "hello world, goodbye universe "

while 1:
    print("\r"),

    cur = hello[i:] + hello[0:i]
    print("%s" % cur),
    sys.stdout.flush()

    i += 1
    if (i >= len(hello)):
        i = 0

    time.sleep(0.3)
```

Comment: When I run this it indeeed does what I want but I am struggling in adapting it to my example. So first I removed the for loop  and just have the index incrementing in the while. but it still goes down every line instead of printing on the spot like your example. pastebin.com/QenmykR9

Comment: it does not seem to be flushing in my case

Comment: if I replace the numpy array in with just a number it works perfectly fine but it seems the numpy array is too big to flush with sys.stdout.flush do you think there is a work around ?

Comment: Based on your pastebin, you're mixing 2.7 and 3.x `print`.  To start, try changing `print(repr(rot_position(o, i)), end="")` to `print(repr(rot_position(o, i)),`.  Or, `print("%s" % repr(rot_position(o, i)),`

Comment: yeah I already fixed that sorry for not updating the pastbin.

Comment: if I replace repr(rot_position(o, i) with i for example which is just a number flushing works but with the big numpy array it doesnt flush

Comment: `print` _should_ be able to handle it, but, IIRC, `sys.stdout.write` should _not_ append newline.  So, you could replace with `sys.stdout.write(repr(rot_position(o,i)))` and it _should_ be able to handle _any_ length

Comment: tried it but nothing I'll keep looking in to it. Not sure why it does not flush

Comment: It may depend upon what `repr` produces.  It _may_ be _empty_ [string], in which case, nothing to flush. Try `cur = repr(rot_position(o,i))` and look at it with debugger.  Or, just pass `cur` to `write/print` and see what happens.

Comment: placed it in to cur also replaced repr with str and same problem how do I look at it with debugger ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/99574/discussion-between-craig-estey-and-francisco-vargas).

Answer (score 8):

you can always use (in Python 3.x):

```
print("sometext", end="")
```

> anything for python 2.7 ?

Add this to the top of your code: `from  __future__ import print_function` You can then use `print` as a function -- [from @rwilson's comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34573305/print-with-no-new-line-python#comment56891845_34573327).

Comment: anything for python 2.7 ? this works for 3 and its useful for me ! but yeah something for 2 would be good too.

Comment: Add this to the top of your code: `from __future__ import print_function` You can then use print as a function.

Answer (score 1):

Erase and reprint the edited line with:

```
def clear_line():
    sys.stdout.write("\033[F") #back to previous line
    sys.stdout.write("\033[K") #clear line
```

then you can do something like:

```
print("Installing... | ")
time.sleep(0.3)
clear_line()
print("Installing... / ")
time.sleep(0.3)
clear_line()
print("Installing... - ")
time.sleep(0.3)
clear_line()
print("Installing... \ ")
```

This will produce a spinning animation. You could do something similar with your numpy array.

Another example:

```
print("1")
print("2")
clear_line():
print("3")
```

Which outputs:

```
1
3
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use for python 2.7

```
print ("sometext", end="")
```